# How to find missing character in the second string when we compare two strings? - Coding Question

Tags: string

If `String a = "abbc"` and `String b="abc"`, we have to print that character 'b' is missing in the second string.

I want to do it by using Java. I am able to do it when String 2 has a character not present in String 1 when s1=abc and s2=abk but not when characters are same in both strings like the one I have mentioned in the question.

```java
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str1  = "abbc";
        String str2 = "abc";

        char first[] = str1.toCharArray();
        char second[] = str2.toCharArray();

        HashMap <Character, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

        for(char a: first){
            if(!map1.containsKey(a)){
                map1.put(a,1);
 
            }else{

            map1.put(a,map1.get(a)+1);

            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(map1);

        HashMap <Character, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

        for(char b: second){
            if(!map2.containsKey(b)){
                map2.put(b,1);

            }else{

            map2.put(b,map2.get(b)+1);

            }
        }
        System.out.println(map2);
    }
}
```

I have two hashmaps here one for the longer string and one for the shorter string, map1 `{a=1,b=2,c=1}` and map2 `{a=1,b=1,c=1}`. What should I do after this?

Comment: I can't really find the right situation you are looking for, as 'b' is not really missing from the second string. Should the number of occurrences of each character be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let assume that we have two strings `a` and `b`.
2. (optional) Compare `lengths` to find longer one.
3. Iterate over them `char` by `char` and compare letters at same index.
4. If both letters are the same, ignore it. If different, add letter from longer string to result and increment index of the longer string by 1.
5. What's left in longer string is your result.

Pseudocode:

```js
const a = "aabbccc"
const b = "aabcc"

let res = ""

for (let i = 0, j = 0; i <= a.length; i++, j++) {
  if (a[i] !== b[j]) { 
    res += a[i]
    i++
  }
}

console.log(res)
```

More modern and elegant way using high order functions:

```js
const a = "aabbccc"
const b = "aabcc"

const res = [...a].reduce((r, e, i) => e === b[i - r.length] ? r : r + e, "")                   
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Can we do it using Hashmap?